# Set intersection with equation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $$m, m'\in A \text{ and }  p, p' \in B \text{ where } m-m'=p'-p $$ does this imply that $$m-m'=p'-p\in A\cap B$$ and why?

The actual instance of my problem is slightly different to this but I want to know if I'm seeing the problem in the wrong way.

edit: A and B can be called subgroups to make sure this holds.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are for example subgroups, you have $m-m'\in A$ and $p-p'\in B$. But $m-m'=p-p'$ so it is in $A\cap B$.


But what are exactly $A$, $B$ and $-$ ?

Comment: @D.L. Could you explain to me a little further why it is in $A \cap B$ it may seem trivial but I don't really understand this. What I don't understand is why, written poorly, $ A = B => A \cap B $. We can call them subgroups if that is what makes them work in this way. It is the logic that I don't get.

Comment: But if it is subgroups, you have $m-m'=p-p'$ so it is both an element of $A$ (because it is $m-m'$) and of $B$ because it is $p-p'$.

Comment: @D.L. I see. For some reason my brain was telling me that these sets need necessarily be disjoint and that was throwing me off. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't, for example, if $A = \{0, 1\}$ and $B = \{1, 2\}$, then $0, 1 \in A$, $1, 2 \in B$, $0 - 1 = 1 - 2 = -1$, but $-1 \not\in A\cap B$.

As pointed out by D.L., if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups under addition, then the conclusion you propose does hold.